# Is $\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{|A\cap B(x,r)|}{|B(x,r)|}\neq 1$?

Tags: measure-theory, limits

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be a Lebesgue measurable set and denote by $|\cdot|$ the Lebesgue measure. Fix some $x\in A$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}^N$. Consider the set $$S_a=\{v\in S^{N-1}:\ \langle a,v\rangle\geq\frac{1}{2}\|a\|\}$$

Suppose that for each $v\in S_a$, there exist $t_v>0$ such that $x+tv\notin A$ for $0<t<t_v$. Can I conclude that $$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{|A\cap B(x,r)|}{|B(x,r)|}\neq 1$$

where $B(x,r)$ denotes the ball in $\mathbb{R}^N$ with center in $x$ and radius $r$?

Edit: Hagen first answer was right, but it was not what I was expecting, so I have changed a little bit the question.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (This was for the original formulation: "Can I conclude that $lim=0$?" instead of "$\lim\ne 1$": Certainly not. Consider $A=\{(x,y)\mid y\le 0\}$, $a=(0,1)$, $x=(0,0)$. Then $t_v=1$ works for all $v\in S_a$ and the limit is $\frac12$.)

Let $$S_{a,n} =\left\{v\in S_a\biggm| \forall t\in\left]0,\frac 1n\right[\colon x+t v\notin A\right\}.$$
Then all  $S_{a,n}$ are measurable and ordered by inclusion and we have $$S_a=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}S_{a,n}.$$
For $n$ big enough, we have $|S_{a,n}|>\frac12|S_a|$ and hence 
$$\lim_{r\to0}\frac{|A\cap B(x,r)|}{|B(x,r)|} \le \frac{|S^{N-1}\setminus S_{a_n}|}{|S^{N-1}|}<1-\frac{|S_a|}{2|S^{N-1}|}.$$